# Movement in 2D Games (round position when blitting?)

Tags: python, animation, pygame, 2d, sprite

I use Python 2.x and Pygame to code games. Pygame has a built-in rect (Rectangle) class that only supports ints instead of floats. So I have made my own rect class (MyRect) which supports floats. Now my question is as follows:

A 2D platformer char moves its position (x, y -> both floats). Now when I blit the char onto the screen, is the position rounded to an int (int(round(x))) or just converted into an int (int(x))? I know this might sound a bit stupid, but I've got an issue with this and I'd like to know how this is usually handled.

Answer (score 1):

You should assume that when blitting a `pygame.Surface`, the position gets converted to an `int` via `int()`

Comment: Thanks for answering. And that is good as it is or should I rather round the position first before blitting? Is it the common way to just flatten the position into ints in game programming?

Comment: Most people just use `int()`. Why does a one pixel difference matter? Just a perfectionist?

Comment: well, in pixely 2D games, 1 pixel can have an impact. And yes, I am bit of a perfectionist. But thanks, this helped